# Stripe retrieve all the paid amount on a product

Tags: stripe-payments

**I'm trying to get the sum of all payments for a product, how can I do it in stripe?**
I've tried it, but it's not the right thing

```
const prices = await stripe.prices.list({ product: productId });
```

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has no native way to do this.

If your Product is recurring, list Invoice and check each lines.data :
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list

If your Product is one-time and you’re not using one-off Invoices, list Checkout Sessions and check each line_items.data (you’ll need to expand line_items) :
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list